# Передать в Invoke параметр с ref

Tags: c#, делегаты

Пытаюсь использовать Invoke для того, чтобы использовать winform-контролы в другом потоке. И один из аргументов у меня по задумке должен быть ref. Столкнувшись с тем, что лямбды не умеют принимать ref, создал кастомный делегат:

```
delegate void MyAction(string source, string path, RichTextBox logText, ref bool? _flag);
```

Далее создаю его экземпляр:

```
            MyAction Scope = new MyAction(
                delegate (string source, string path, RichTextBox logText, ref bool? _flag)
                {
                    Scope_Save(source, path, logText, ref _flag);
                });
```

И в конце концов пытаюсь использовать так:

```
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => {
                    this.Invoke(Scope, sourceText.Text, folderPath, statusView, ref flag);
                },
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            );
```

Но компилятор не хочет там видеть ref. Дословно: "аргумент `5` не должен передаваться к ключевым словом ref". Получается, что нет никакой возможности его туда передать?

Comment: Какому классу принадлежит ваш метод this.Invoke? К сожалению такой метод есть у большого количества классов. Я попытался воссоздать вашу ситуацию, но у меня проблем с компиляцией не возникло - https://youtu.be/oOrOetqYiZw

Comment: Это главная форма приложения

Comment: так `Invoke` метод не принимает 5 параметров: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Там идет сигнатура `Control.Invoke)Delegate method, params object[] args)` - то есть переменное количество параметров

Comment: Ошибка от того, что внутри `params object[] args` не ожидается передачи аргументов по ссылке. Но благодаря `MethodInvoker` можно использовать перегрузку `Invoke` с одним аргументом и передавать туда сразу анонимный делегат или лямбду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдельный тип делегата не потребовался, вот такое компилируется:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsLambdaRef
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool? _flag;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async Task DoTheWork()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => {
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                    {
                        Scope_Save("", "", null, ref _flag);
                    }));
                },
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            );
        }

        private void Scope_Save(string source, string path, RichTextBox logText, ref bool? flag)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Видео о том, как делался ответ на вопрос: https://youtu.be/OBAZ9SwSpvs

Comment: Да, вроде запускается!

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется, это то, что надо

Comment: Добавил видео о том, как я делал ответ.

Comment: Когда записываете видео, думайте о зрителях прежде всего. Шрифт кода надо делать крупнее, убрать лишнее с экрана, например внизу окно Output открыто и нафиг съедает 1/4 видимого от окна редактора кода. Если вы никак не комментируете по ходу записи свои действия, то хоть пишите в коде комментарии, что пишите и для чего.

Comment: @Bulson у вас какой размер экрана?

Comment: HD------1920x1080

Comment: @Bulson очень странно, у меня именно такое же, и видео оригинал в таком разрешении - 1080p60 весь текст видно отлично в полноэкранном режиме. В любом случае, спасибо за рекомендации - я их постараюсь учесть.

Comment: Есть люди у которых могут быть проблемы со зрением... У вас похоже ситуация как в поговорке: "сытый голодного не разумеет".